# Show that if $\mathfrak{p}_L/\mathfrak{p}_K$ and $\mathfrak{p}_M/\mathfrak{p}_K$ is unramified, then $\mathfrak{p}_LM/\mathfrak{p}_K$ is as well.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

So the setting is $K$ is a fraction field of a Dedekind domain $R$ and $L/K, M/K, N/K$ are field extensions of the $K$. The integral closures of $K$ in $L, M, N$ respectively are $\mathcal{O}_L$, $\mathcal{O}_M$, $\mathcal{O}_N$ and the necessary primes are $\mathfrak{p}_K,\mathfrak{p}_L,\mathfrak{p}_M,\mathfrak{p}_N$. I need to show that if $\mathfrak{p}_L/\mathfrak{p}_K$ and $\mathfrak{p}_M/\mathfrak{p}_K$ is unramified, then $\mathfrak{p}_LM/\mathfrak{p}_K$ is unramified given that $N=LM$.

I'm having trouble understanding what $\mathfrak{p}_L/\mathfrak{p}_K$ is for example. Am I right in understanding that $\mathfrak{p}_L = \mathfrak{p}_K \mathcal{O}_L$?

My guess is that I need to work with the fact that if a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified then $\mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_L$ is a product of separable field extensions. Am I on the right track or am I completely off? Any help would be appreciated.